# Bash shell script not working

Tags: bash, shell

I have a script I am trying to work out to scan my LAN and send me notification if there is a new MAC address that does not appear in my master list. I believe my variables may be messed up. This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=$HOME/maclist.log
MASTERFILE=$HOME/master
FILEDIFF="$(diff $LIST $MASTERFILE)"

# backup the maclist first
if [ -f $LIST ]; then
       cp $LIST maclist_`date +%Y%m%H%M`.log.bk
else
        touch $LIST
fi 

# this will scan the network and extract the IP and MAC address
nmap -n -sP 192.168.122.0/24 | awk '/^Nmap scan/{IP=$5};/^MAC/{print IP,$3};{next}' > $LIST

# this will use a diff command to compare the maclist created above and master list of known good devices on the LAN
if [ $FILEDIFF ] 2> /dev/null; then
        echo
        echo "---- All is well on `date` ----" >> macscan.log
        echo
else
       # echo -e "\nWARNING!!" | `mutt -e 'my_hdr From:user@email.com' -s "WARNIG!! NEW DEVICE ON THE LAN" -i maclist.log user@email.com`
        echo "emailing you"
fi
```

When I execute this when the maclist.log does not exist I get this response:

```
diff: /root/maclist.log: No such file or directory
```

If I execute it again with the maclist.log file existing the file gets renamed from the cp line without any issue.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why don't you just execute `FILEDIFF="$(diff $LIST $MASTERFILE)"` after your first conditional block (`if [ -f $LIST ] ...`) ?

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte So I tried that and I get no error but the FILEDIFF variable still does not work because I get that email. Or, there could be something wrong with my if [ $FILEDIFF ] statement.

Comment: @t3kg33k `FILEDIFF=diff ...` will be an empty string if `diff` didn't find any difference between the files. You can then check if `FILEDIFF` is an empty string or not with `if [[ "$diff" == "" ]];then ...`

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte Ah! Okay. That makes sense now. And that worked.
Thanks!
Now, how do I promote your answer as the correct answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
FILEDIFF="$(diff $LIST $MASTERFILE)"
```

executes the diff *when it is run* (not when you use `$FILELIST` later). At that time the list file hasn't been created.

The easiest fix is just to put the diff command in full where `$FILELIST` is currently used.